# Почему не роботает z-index у before?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок с карточками в каждой карточке есть before з цифрой которая должна быть под низом самой карточки я пробовал что-то делать не получается не пойму в чем проблема
[image: photo]

Проект на codepen `<https://codepen.io/Zhenya-Tureysky/pen/BaOyBOd>`

Comment: Потому что у родителя этого псевдоэлемента присутствует `backdrop-filter`. Выход: делать не псевдоэлементом и выносить из блока с фильтром.

Comment: спасибо все получилось